# Finding all the visual studio projects a file belongs to

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a visual studio solution with over 30 projects and multiple filters.

What is the easiest way to determine all the projects a file belongs too?

Comment: A file should typically belong to just one project, otherwise you will run into serious problems on the long term.

Comment: And how can I find that one project? (I just wrote "all" to be more general :-)

It is not my project by the way, but from the company I just started working for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, open a command shell window and create a list of all project files in a text file. For example, for C# projects (having the ending .csproj), run this command in the root folder of your solution:

```
dir /s /b *.csproj >projectlist.txt
```

Then, you can easily determine all projects containing a specific file by the command

```
findstr /f:projectlist.txt /m Name_Of_Your_File
```

Just a suggestion: you can avoid much trouble for the future if you make sure each project has it's own folder, and all files belonging to that project are in or below that folder.

Comment: small caveat, this finds all projects containing files whose name *contains* `Name_Of_Your_File`: if you are looking for `bar.cs` it will also find the project containing `foobar.cs`.

Comment: @user1735003: of course. This can be mitigated by using regular expressions, probably `findstr /f:projectlist.txt /R /m [^a-zA-Z_]Name_Of_Your_File[^a-zA-Z_]`, but I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use AgentRansack or similar tool that allows searching text contained in a file.

Use the following settings:
File Name: *.csproj
Containing Text: YourCodeFile.cs
Look in: YourSolutionFolder

Run the search and you will get a list of all project files that are holders of the CS file.